# fastest way to select row from table1 which is not in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table

```
table1
=======================================
tid    subcategory     category
---------------------------------------
1      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY1
2      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY2
3      SUBCATEGORY2    CATEGORY1
4      SUBCATEGORY3    CATEGORY1
5      SUBCATEGORY4    CATEGORY1
6      SUBCATEGORY5    CATEGORY1
7      SUBCATEGORY6    CATEGORY1
8      SUBCATEGORY7    CATEGORY1
9      SUBCATEGORY8    CATEGORY1
10     SUBCATEGORY9    CATEGORY1


table2 //which have more than 600k rows
=======================================
t2id   subcategory     category  pid
---------------------------------------
1      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY1  1
2      SUBCATEGORY1    CATEGORY2  1
3      SUBCATEGORY2    CATEGORY1  1
```

I try to show all rows of table1 which is not in table2, the result should be like this...

```
=======================================
tid    subcategory     category
---------------------------------------
4      SUBCATEGORY3    CATEGORY1
5      SUBCATEGORY4    CATEGORY1
6      SUBCATEGORY5    CATEGORY1
7      SUBCATEGORY6    CATEGORY1
8      SUBCATEGORY7    CATEGORY1
9      SUBCATEGORY8    CATEGORY1
10     SUBCATEGORY9    CATEGORY1
```

I am using this query and its working for me but it taking to much time plesae tell me the fastest way

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.subcategory, t1.category
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.pid = '1'
                    AND t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory
                    AND t2.category = t1.category);
```

I am using php with mysql..

Comment: Why not use a LEFT JOIN instead?

Comment: sorry but  I dont have idea about this can you help me?

Comment: put `explain` before your query to see which part has problem. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Here `pid` in `table2` is the `tid` from your table 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments i presume category,subcategory  combination can be repeated in table2 for different pids.If so could you try below,

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.subcategory, t1.category
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
                                (SELECT category,subcategory,count(*) 
                                FROM table2 t2
                                WHERE t2.pid = '1'
                                group by category,subcategory) t2
                  WHERE t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory
                    AND t2.category = t1.category);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine -- even perhaps the best way to do it.

For this query, though:

```
SELECT t1.tid, t1.subcategory, t1.category
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.pid = 1 AND   -- pid is probably a number so do not use single quotes
                        t2.subcategory = t1.subcategory AND
                        t2.category = t1.category
                 );
```

For this query to have good performance, you want an index on `table2(category, subcategory, pid)`.

Comment: pid have a lots of  number I am using single here just for show example

Comment: @SmartDeveloper . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You did not reply to my comment but I guess here is the solution you are looking for :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.* FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.tid = table2.t1id
WHERE table2.t2id IS NULL
```

This should be faster than the `NOT EXISTS` but you have to have an extra field in the `table2` which accepts the `tid` from `table1`. This makes a relation between the two tables. However, if `pid` in `table2` stores `tid` value from `table1` (which I asked in the comment above) then you do not need to create an extra field. In that case, just replace `t1id` with `pid` and it should go fine. Compare the speed now and let us know in the comments.

Check Fiddle: [DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xAjPt62MK4Tcmpz3EUffkb/0)

Comment: You did not reply to my comment so I was not sure about the `pid` and that's why it took me time to answer it. If you would have replied to my comment earlier, I would have made it quick.

Comment: sorry  for late but according to your db fiddle you presume t1id is unique in table2 but its not, and pid means person id which come from another table and each pid can have unique t1id but t1id in not unique in table2

Comment: if it possible to do this with pid then I think your answer will be the best becos of using left join

Comment: I will use CAPITALS to point to some specific things. There HAS to be a relation between the two tables in order to connect them. Unless you connect them you CANNOT use JOINS. And to connect them you have to pass the primary key ID from table1 to table2. If you missed doing that in the beginning and now you have 600K records them I am afraid you can't be helped. Take it as a lesson. Whenever you make a project and there are tables like CATEGORIES, SUBCATEGORIES & CHILD CATEGORIES (like in ecommerce) you MUST have a relation between them to avoid conflict in future.

Comment: For now other than my answer there is no other FASTER method. If you can somehow make changes to your database and have an additional field in the table2 like `t1id` then you can simply implement my code and you have the FASTEST query for now. Also, you know and accepted that mine one would be the fastest, it's however your database tables that have flaws to not be able to use this, my answer is still neither accepted nor up voted. Thanks :)